# Does another user's edit kill the Tumbleweed?

Tags: discussion, edits, tumbleweed-badge

If a question's a candidate for a Tumbleweed and someone edits it (retags, rewords, etc), does that edit nullify the badge?  I'm assuming no, but not positive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `[Tumbleweed]` Asked a question with no answers, no comments, and low views for a week.

Editing is neither an answer nor a comment. Just the view count goes up.

Comment: The question is about a badge. This answer doesn't seem to address that.

Comment: @jdk: It does address that. It points out that editing counts as neither an answer nor a comment, but simply bumps the question to the top of the active list, potentially giving it more views. The number of views are a factor in awarding the badge.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the clarification. My mind hadn't made that final link about edits being bumped up, so I didn't initially understand why edits translated into view counts.

Answer (score 1):

No, it should not -- as Georg pointed out none of the Tumbleweed metrics are *directly* related to editing.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  Accepting Georg's answer since he was first!